# Struts2 -Unable to display String value in jsp file

Tags: jsp, struts2

I created a Dynamic Web Project that uses Struts 2 framework. My problem is that I cannot display the string in my jsp file. I already have my getters and setters.

The message "Hello from execute" displays in the console, but the text I set in the properties are not being displayed. Tried to set the value by using equal operator and by setters to ensure that Im setting a value. Tried to search online on how to get property value but none of them is working on my issue.

Here is my action class:

```
package com.tutorial.action;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class TutorialAction extends ActionSupport{

    private String userName;
    private String password;

    public String execute() {
        System.out.print("Hello from execute");
        userName = "Test";
        setPassword("Test");
        return "success";
    }

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }    
}
```

error.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        <s:property value="userName"/>
        <s:property value="password"/>
    </h2>
</body>
</html>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
        "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
        "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">

    <struts>
        <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true"/>

        <package name="default" namespace="/hello" extends="struts-default">
            <action name="getTutorial" method="execute" class="com.tutorial.action.TutorialAction">
                <result name="success">/error.jsp</result>
            </action>
        </package>
    </struts>
```

Comment: I also tried rendering in Edge and Chrome but nothing happens.

Comment: There's no trivial way to debug this; there's nothing obviously wrong. You'd need to create a repo w/ the minimal failing example in it. Unrelated, but specifying `execute` as the method, and result `name` as `"success"` is redundant.